# SQLi Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysqli query given below

```
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['content']);    
$query = "SELECT id,siteName,address,latitude,longitude,info,budget,tts,markerType FROM maptable WHERE siteName = '". $content ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

I'm currently confused right now because I am using this script for my ajax call but when i tried to remove the WHERE clause, the query function works, when I include the WHERE clause looking for the Id it still works but when I tried to use the WHERE clause on any database fields starting form siteName,address,etc it fails and returns an empty value how is that happening? is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Is your ajax call transfering the GET value correct? Maybe it is empty.

Comment: have you tried  `'SELECT .... siteName = "$content";'`    Also, check your 'content' before useing it in a query, to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Use PDO instead. And debug your query. And check that that value exist in the database.

Comment: @stefan it is transferring the correct value. If I use WHERE id = 'x' (where x is some data) it output values correctly but when i tried different fields it returns empty.

Comment: @lxer how can I check my content to prevent sql injection? Already did what you said and still returns empty

Comment: @dan-klasson values are existing in the database sir. I'm not familiar with PDO

Comment: Then print out the value of $query. And get familiar with PDO. Because what you have above is a huge security hole.

Comment: Is the value in the database also escaped?

Comment: @dan-klasson if i print out Id it works, everything is transformed into xml but when I tried to ouput my data using siteNames, latitude,longitude etc my database returns empty. With the PDO part I will take your advice and study to learn them Thank you sir

Comment: @stefan what do you mean sir by the value in my database is also escaped?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an GET value with to corresponding row from the database?

Comment: @stefan is the above example insufficient sir? apart from id everything returns empty. When I used id as my query source it returns data from the corresponding id value but when I use the others like MarkerType WHERE MarkerType = Park it returns empty even though I have a Park record on my field

Comment: @JeiShiiDeiji It would really help to see what you get via the $_GET parameter and what data you store in the database. Maybe you need to trim the $_GET data, but it could also be an encoding issue. Hard to say if there is not data to compare.

Comment: @stefan sorry sir for spending your time. It appears that it was my fault why my query fails. I used the LIKE clause and now everything is working. Anyway thank you again sir for your time in helping me.